# Hide snackBar from one fragment, when change tab in viewpager

Tags: android

I have a viewpager with 2 fragments. In the second fragment, I am displaying snackbar (using a view in the fragment). I would like to hide that snackbar when the user swipes to the first tab. I don't know why if the bar is being displayed in a layout of a fragment, I can see it in other fragment.

Comment: What I do is display the snackbar on the activity. I render it from the activity and display it or hide it when the swipe is made

Answer (score 0):

For viewpager when user swipes from one screen to another screen(fragment)
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() will gets invoked you can handle here.

Comment: I know but the snackbar is being created from one of the fragments and not from de container

Comment: by using call back once page is going to swipe you can call that method you can perform hiding  snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoordinatorLayout for your fragment.

As per android documentation:
**"The method actually searches up the view hierarchy from the passed view until it reaches either a CoordinatorLayout, or the window decor's content view"**

Using coordinatorLayout for your fragment will attach the snackbar to the fragment, so when you swipe it wont overlap with other fragment.

If your fragment is using other than CoordinatorLayout, enclose your layout with CoordinatorLayout.

Documentation link https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing